# Displaying view function in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

I am trying to display the result of my view function on a Django webpage but only get one line with no hyperlink.

code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import feedparser

def index(content):
    YahooContent = feedparser.parse ("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/")
    for feed in YahooContent.entries:
            content = (feed.title + ": " + "\n"+feed.link + "\n" + feed.published + "\n")
            return HttpResponse(content)
```

Result on the webpage:

Man arrested in death of missing Ariz. girl:  http://news.yahoo.com/arizona-girls-home-searched-body-found-154919366.html Thu, 04 Sep 2014 14:05:16 -0400

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to collect feeds in a list and only then, after the loop, return an `HttpResponse` instance:

```
content = []
for feed in YahooContent.entries:
    content.append(feed.title + ": " + "\n" + feed.link + "\n" + feed.published)

return HttpResponse('\n'.join(content))
```

---

Another option, that would follow [Django philosophies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/) about separation of concerns, would be to [create and render a template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) and pass the data into the template context:

- create a template, let's say `index.html` with the following content

  ```
  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Link</th>
          <th>Published</th>
      </tr>
      {% for entry in entries %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{ entry.title }}</td>
              <td>{{ entry.link }}</td>
              <td>{{ entry.published }}</td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </table>
  ```
- put the template into `templates` directory of your app or project
- render it in the view using, for example, [`render_to_response()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)

  ```
  from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
  import feedparser

  def index(content):
      entries = feedparser.parse ("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/").entries
      return render_to_response('index.html', {'entries': entries})
  ```

Comment: that worked to display all content but still displays all as a single string. I want to be able to  separate the news and also display the hyperlinks.

Comment: @Amir okay, I've provided you with an alternative, better approach.

Answer (score 0):

your 'return' statement is inside the for loop due to which it is returning after the first iteration itself and hence giving just one feed instead of all, to be able to return all feeds you need to build a list of all the feeds and then return that.

Comment: I don't see the point to duplicate the answer after 5 minutes. Also, that would not really help without the actual code.

Comment: I apologize but I dint see your answer before as had opened this question and then went to read my mails and then typed the answer.